# Does 'work' mean 'working' or 'my job' here?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, idiomatic-language

> Friend/Colleague: *I know he only wants the best for you. So do I. I
> would like to see you back at work, and--*
>
> Man: ***Work? I don't care about work.***

Would 'work' in the bold-face line of dialog mean 'I don't care about working' or 'I don't care about my job'?

Comment: work, the noun. But the basic meaning would be the same about the ing as working is also a noun.

Comment: As usual - _it all depends on the context_.